# why are font sizes off by a factor of 1.35 (too small) with Delphi FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In a Delphi FMX applicatoin, why are font sizes off by a factor of 1.35 (too small). For example, if I put a TMemo on a FMX form and change the TextSettings.font.size to 72, the spacing between the lines should be exactly 1" (as the are in VCL). But to get the same spacing I need change memo scaling to 1.35 of make the font 97.2 points.  Oddly the fonts are also the wrong size in the dialog to select a font. Is this a bug or do I have something set wrong?

I do have a large monitor but not scaled the fonts (Windows 10) and everything reports that it is seeing the default 96 dpi.

Target in currently Win32 (I have not tried it on OSX yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Embarcadero web site](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42535):

> Font sizes in FMX are expressed in device-independent pixels (DIPs),
>   96 per logical inch. Font sizes in VCL are expressed in points, 72 per
>   logical inch. Therefore, text using the same Font.Size is smaller in
>   FireMonkey.

As such, the ratio is 96/72 = 1.3333.

**Edit:** Came across this [very nice explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173(v=vs.85).aspx) on the MSDN web site about Dots Per Inch (DPI) vs Device Independent Pixels (DIP). Relevant to why FMX uses DIP.

Comment: I see the math works out. Yet this link says it in points: [Link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Graphics.TFont.Size)

Comment: I confirmed that in OSX the font size is treated as points and on Windows FMX, the font size is in DIPs (points in VCL). Clearly a bug if you want the same code to work on both.  In the meantime, I'll catch it with OS condition statements.

Comment: Or, maybe one could consider this the correct behavior.  If DIB = Pixel than the ratio of the text to the rest of the form would be the same in both OSX and Win32. It just would be measure smaller in Windows (96ppi) compared to OSX (72ppi). The only time you would have to multiply the font size by 96/72 is if a Windows user is allowed to set the font size in a WYSIWIG environment. (like a document editor)

Comment: @BillF I believe that is the correct and indeed the intent with which FMX uses DIP...